# How do I select the nth file from a directory in vba, and how can I retrieve the file name of the nth image in a word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Trying to loop through all the images in a word document, and rename images in a particular directory to the file name found in 'Edit Links to Files'.

It should be a very simple for loop but I'm not super familiar with VBA so I'm not sure how to write it.

Skeleton code:

```
Sub renameimages()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim nameindoc as String
    Dim currentfilename as String
    
    For i = 1 to .Inlineshapes.Count
        'get nth inlineshape in document
        'Set nameindoc As (name of file in document)
        'get nth file from a directory
        'Set currentfilename As (name of file from directory)
        Name currentfilename As nameindoc
    Next i
End Sub
```

I'm just struggling on how exactly

1. To select the nth file from the directory.
2. To retrieve the name of the file of the nth image in the document.

Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to get you started. You're going to have to figure out what "nth file in a directory" means. This code assumes it means the nth file that the `Dir()` function returns, but that may not be what you want.

```
Const sPath As String = "C:\Mypath\"

Public Sub RenameThirdImage()
    
    Dim lCnt As Long
    Dim shp As InlineShape
    Dim sThird As String
    Dim sFile As String
    
    For Each shp In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        If lCnt = 3 Then
            sThird = shp.LinkFormat.SourceName
        End If
    Next shp
    
    sFile = Dir(sPath & "*.gif")
    lCnt = 0
    
    Do While Len(sFile) > 0
        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        If lCnt = 3 Then
            Name sPath & sFile As sPath & sThird
            Exit Do
        End If
        sFile = Dir
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

This loops through all the InlineShapes and stores the name of the third one. Then it loops through all the files in a directory and uses the `Name...As...` command to change the file name.